# Can I add Unicode 8.0 support in Java 8

Tags: java, unicode

Is it possible to add Unicode 8.0 support in Java 8 by downloading any type of patch file? Or I have to move to Java 9?

Comment: Major (stable) Java versions are considered feature complete. Bugfixes and security enhancements are added, but no new features. You will have to update I'm afraid.

Comment: What does “Unicode 8.0 support” actually mean?  Character properties?  Character names?  Unicode blocks?  Rendering characters in Java2D/Swing?  Rendering characters in JavaFX?

Comment: @VGR Yeah mainly the lack of Character info. Like isDefined, isIdeographic, isLetter, and getName return null and false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No back-port

Support for [Unicode 7 and Unicode 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Versions) were added to [Java 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), documented on the [JDK 9 project page](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/).

- [JEP 227: Unicode 7.0](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/227)
- [JEP 267: Unicode 8.0](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/267)

No implementation of Java 8 that I know of has back-ported support for later Unicode. I suppose that might be possible. You might do so yourself by compiling from an open-source implementation of Java such as [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK), if you were highly motivated.

Instead, I suggest migrating to Java 9 or later if you must have support for later Unicode. Note that Java 9 is [no longer supported free-of-cost](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nFGazvrCvHMZJgFstlbzoHjpAVwv5DEdnaBr_5pKuHo/edit), not that I know of.

[Java 10](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/10/) adds:

- [JEP 314: Additional Unicode Language-Tag Extensions](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/314)

[Java 11](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/11/) adds:

- [JEP 327: Unicode 10](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/327)
  (and also includes the 7,500 characters and six new scripts of [Unicode 9](https://unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/))

Comment: Thanks for the response. Since there's not LTS for Java 9 and 10, in my case it's  Java 11 next. Unfortunately enterprises are not always so quick to update.